# Scala speed test and profiler

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm interested in speed test and performance of my application. For example how much time was spent to db query (I use squeryl ORM).

Are there any plugins for Intellij-Idea IDE?

Comment: Maybe running VisualVM (http://visualvm.java.net/) will give you enough information already? There is a plugin for IntelliJ to start it from the IDE: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7115?pr=idea

Comment: YourKit Java Profiler (http://www.yourkit.com/) is great and has very good integration with Eclipse and IntelliJ. Unfortunately, it's not free (but has 15-day free trial).

Comment: Not an Intellij plugin, but you may want to have a look at thyme: https://github.com/Ichoran/thyme

Comment: http://axel22.github.io/scalameter/ is another option - similar to thyme.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for plugins for Intellij-IDEA, then the YourKit profiler can be integrated into this IDE. YourKit profilers might be difficult to use to measure the exact time in a specific part of code.

You should consider using a microbenchmarking framework such as [ScalaMeter](http://axel22.github.io/scalameter/) for this. In this framework you write tests similar to unit tests, that can be run selectively to verify that the performance hasn't changed. It can be neatly integrated with SBT -- you can run it as a test.

Answer (score 3):

Since Scala runs in JVM how about jvisualvm , although not an intellij plugin : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html